# Out of all the crypto-currencies, which address format is the shortest?

Tags: address, currencies

Bitcoin addresses ranges from 24-28 characters and so is litecoin. Monero is 90+ characters. Which crypto currency address format is the shortest that is in the top 50 of coinmarketcap?

Comment: My SuperShitCoin has address range 1 char. Would you like to test it?

Comment: Bitcoin/Litecoin addresses are usually 34 characters. Monero is usually 95.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at those coins addresses? If you are looking for someone to do that for you, so I think this should not be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nxt addresses are the shortest. They only have 20 characters.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem to be a good idea to only differentiate between the "number of characters". Some addresses are alphanumeric (Bitcoin), others are only hexadecimal (Ethereum), others are only numeric (LISK)...

---

What I found out:

NXT has 24 characters (example: `NXT-MT4P-AHG4-A4NA-CCMM2`), only 20 without the static hyphens, only 17 without the static "NXT" in the beginning.

Lisk has 21 characters (example: `16118128613908223361L`), only 20 without the static 'L' in the end.

Comment: How does that pan out in a binary representation?

Answer (score 1):

NXT. It has 20 digits only, cant think of anything shorter.